# Generate color combination from one color

Tags: java, colors

I need to generate a color combination (monochromatic, triad, analogous, split, etc) from one color in Java. Just like they do in  [kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com), only I want to present it in a JSP page). How can I get the RGB value of the colors in the color combination? Is there a formula or API to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what all those terms mean, but you might find that using [HSL Color](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) values may make it easier to find related colors.