# [Android Studio ]Obtaining Analogous colors from an other color

Tags: java, colors, palette

I want to do color harmonies (Analogous in priority) in Java for Android studio. I Use ColorMatrix but I don't know the formula or is there another way? Maybe with HSV?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about this myself (I'm searching this up) but found two other similar questions you can check out ::

[Generate color combination from one color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401440/generate-color-combination-from-one-color)

and

[searching harmonious colors for current color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010372/searching-harmonious-colors-for-current-color)

PS I posted this as an answer as I cannot comment ...